# Trying to open InfoBox with PushPin click event and Bing Maps / JavaScript

Tags: javascript, bing-maps

I am experimenting with the sample code on the Bing SDK site but am unable to get the click event to work with the pushpins I am adding in a JS .each loop that pulls in longitude, latitude coordinates from a sql server.  I can get the push pins to display fine, I can get the InfoBoxes to display fine if I set their visible to true in the loop, but if I set the visible property to false in the loop and then try to set visible to true with the pushpin click event nothing happens.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

      $(document).ready(function () {

        var map = null;
        var pinInfobox = null;

        function LoadMap() {
            map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById('myMap'), {credentials: "Aq85qFzkJkdfauSc1nXq3IATrqgPGN77_MBhghypyJ94ygTElWHSHYv3WXYZT-3E"} );
        }

        function displayInfobox(e) {
            defaultInfobox.setOptions({ visible: true });
        }

        LoadMap();

        var url = "/Job/GetLocations";
        $.getJSON(url, null, function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (index, LocationData) {
                var pushpin = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(map.getCenter(), { text: '' });                                  
                pushpin.setLocation(new Microsoft.Maps.Location(LocationData.Latitude, LocationData.Longitude));               

                var Route = LocationData.PickupCity + ' to ' + LocationData.DeliveryCity;
                var Details = 'Pays $' + LocationData.Payment + '<br>' + 'Pickup ' + LocationData.PickupHour + LocationData.PickupMinute + '<br>' + 'Deliver ' + LocationData.DeliveryHour + LocationData.DeliveryMinute;
                var infoboxOptions = { visible: false, title: Route, description: Details }; 
                var defaultInfobox = new Microsoft.Maps.Infobox(new Microsoft.Maps.Location(LocationData.Latitude, LocationData.Longitude), infoboxOptions);
                Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(pushpin, 'click', displayInfobox);
                map.entities.push(pushpin);
                map.entities.push(defaultInfobox);                                     

            });
            map.setView({ zoom: 7, center: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(34.470639154314995, -118.55275198817253) });
        });

      });

  </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

the trick is that there should only be 1 instance of an infoBox on the page.
Each click of a pushpin will just overwrite the title and content of the single infoBox and move it to the location of your clicked pin.

Here's the answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7663993/multiple-pushpin-with-infobox-in-bing-map

I modified your sample to use some random points and tested this out since I don't have access do your datasource.  My tests worked fine.

To adapt your code sample with your dataset (I'm not able to test, but..):

```
      <script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {

  var map = null;
  var pinInfobox = null;
  var infoboxLayer = new Microsoft.Maps.EntityCollection();

  function LoadMap() {
      map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById('myMap'), {credentials: "Aq85qFzkJkdfauSc1nXq3IATrqgPGN77_MBhghypyJ94ygTElWHSHYv3WXYZT-3E"} );

      var infoboxOptions = { visible: false, title: "title", description: "description" };
      pinInfobox = new Microsoft.Maps.Infobox(new Microsoft.Maps.Location(0, 0), infoboxOptions);
      infoboxLayer.push(pinInfobox);
      map.entities.push(infoboxLayer);

      var url = "/Job/GetLocations";
      $.getJSON(url, null, function (data) {
          $.each(data, function (index, LocationData) {
              var pushpin = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(map.getCenter(), { text: '' });
              pushpin.setLocation(new Microsoft.Maps.Location(LocationData.Latitude, LocationData.Longitude));

              pushpin.Title = LocationData.PickupCity + ' to ' + LocationData.DeliveryCity;
              pushpin.Description = 'Pays $' + LocationData.Payment + '<br>' + 'Pickup ' + LocationData.PickupHour + LocationData.PickupMinute + '<br>' + 'Deliver ' + LocationData.DeliveryHour + LocationData.DeliveryMinute;
              Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(pushpin, 'click', displayInfobox);
              map.entities.push(pushpin);                                    

          });
          map.setView({ zoom: 7, center: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(34.470639154314995, -118.55275198817253) });
      });
  }

  function displayInfobox(e) {
      pinInfobox.setOptions({ title: e.target.Title, description: e.target.Description, visible: true, offset: new Microsoft.Maps.Point(0, 25) });
      pinInfobox.setLocation(e.target.getLocation());
  }

  LoadMap();
});
```